# Query for nested fields returns results as if there was no nested mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, mapping

I am having difficulties understanding, why a query across nested fields is returning unexpected results.

I have the following template for my index

```
PUT /_template/nested_test
{
  "index_patterns": [ "nested-*" ],
  "settings": { "index.mapping.coerce": false },
  "mappings": { 
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties" {
      "vNested": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
           "v1": { "type": "keyword" },
           "v2": {
               "properties": {
                  "v21": {
                    "type": long"
                  }
               }
           }
         }
       }
     } 
  }
}
```

I will post two documents to an index that matches the template.

```
POST /nested-example/_doc
{
  "vNested": [
    {
      "v1": "User1",
      "v2": {
        "v21": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "v1": "User3",
      "v2": {
        "v21": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
POST /nested-example/_doc
{
  "vNested": [
    {
      "v1": "User1",
      "v2": {
        "v21": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "v1": "User2",
      "v2": {
        "v21": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I will create a query with the goal of only getting the results of those documents, where there exists User1 with a corresponding v21 value of 3. As far as I understand, my nested mapping should ensure that I will only get the second document as query result.

The following query:

```
GET /nested-example/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested: {
                "path": "vNested",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "vNested.v1": "User1"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested: {
                "path": "vNested",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "vNested.v2.v21": "3"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

returns both documents, not only the single document that I expected

I understand that the query string is not the most elegant - this is due to some business logic + front-end framework logic in place for creating the query strings based on user input and any suggestions on how to remove redundancies there are welcome as well.

However I struggle to understand why does this query return both documents including the one where the vNested object with v1=User1, and v21=1. Shouldn't the nested mapping of the vNested field prevent just that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`bool/must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query inside the [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) since you are querying on a single object and not on multiple objects. Modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "vNested",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "vNested.v1": "User1"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "vNested.v2.v21": "3"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "inner_hits":{}
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result is

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "nested-example",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "AAu0IXkBKyWl6Va6kmTU",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "vNested": [
            {
              "v1": "User1",
              "v2": {
                "v21": 3
              }
            },
            {
              "v1": "User2",
              "v2": {
                "v21": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "vNested": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.6931472,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "nested-example",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "AAu0IXkBKyWl6Va6kmTU",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "vNested",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.6931472,
                  "_source": {
                    "v1": "User1",
                    "v2": {
                      "v21": 3
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Mihkel Künnapas please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will update as soon as I can validate, if this fixes my issue.

Comment: Thank you again, I was able to check that this does indeed solve my issue. Could You please elaborate one more thing to see if I understood Your explanation correctly. You say in your answer that I need to add my bool/must query INSIDE the nested query, because I am querying on a single object. Does "single object" in this case mean that all the fields I am querying have the same nested path? And multiple objects would mean I have some separate nested objects (with different nested paths) and I would need to keep these as separate nested queries?